Looking for way to share location data between apps
It is unnecessarily difficult to share geo data between apps. Pick a location in one app and share it with your navigation app? Nope. Park the car in maps and send the location to your smart watch? Nope. Apart from a few exceptions, it is all just impossible.
I don't know if it's by design to keep you from using a competitors app, or if there is just no good standard for geo data in Android, but I needed some 3rd party app to convert the geo data for me. I used Map2Geo (catfish.android.map2geo) plus the 'url injector' (catfish.android.map2geo.urlinjector) by Catfish for that. For a while life was uncomplicated. Then, Map2Geo got removed from the Play Store, even though it looks clean. There is a mirror with the original description, but I don't trust unofficial sources.
Now I have become increasingly frustrated not being able to do simple things that I know are technically possible. I have searched everywhere for an alternative method of achieving something that could be called "universal sharing of geo data between apps". I can't even find others asking the same question. Am I missing something obvious? Is there a trick, plugin, hack or a tool similar to map2geo that does the conversion between apps locally?

Hi, please note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not put any restriction for apps-only, so we'd appreciate it if you could [edit] the question, add some details, and/or remove the restriction. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, Software Recommendations Stack Exchange instead.

Hi @AndrewT. I didn't mean to add restrictions, I just want a solution that works. I've edited the message slightly in the hopes that it will remove such confusion. Do you have a solution for me?

Thanks for the edit. As for the solution, I'm afraid I don't have a satisfying solution. I believe geo URI scheme should be the solution, e.g. OsmAnd supports sharing as geo:, which Google Maps and Waze can open it. However, I don't know the support of other mapping apps. Even Google Maps makes it hard to get the coordinate for potential automation (ref: How to copy the coordinate (latitude/longitude) in Google Maps?).

Also on SoftwareRecs.SE: Looking for Map2Geo alternative to share location data between Android apps
